# What is the preferred way of iterating over main()?

Tags: java

I have a main() method that essentially plays a game with some random elements in it. For a school project, I'm developing an algorithm to play the game and would like to measure the performance changes as I progress with the program. Thus, I need to iterate over main() a large number of times and record analytics data of each run.

What is the preferred method of doing this? I can, of course, embed the original contents of main() in a `while` or `for` loop and add the analytics calls in and after that. However, I have a kind of a gut feeling that there is a better and (since I'm studying this stuff) more professional way. Also, I'd like to keep the original program as unchanged as possible.

Or would it be better to discard implementing this into the actual program itself and look at perhaps the IDE doing the iteration by just running the program from start to finish many times?

As always, big thanks!

Comment: Are you using right OO design principles? I believe you should at least have a single TOP level class named Game which you should instantiate and use from main. Then you can wrap it in while loop to measure performance of multiple runs.

Comment: I would, however this situation arises from the fact that I've been supplied the game logic etc by the uni and am only supposed to make changes to a single class that is the bot I'm supposed to write. Everyone's classes are then extracted and pitted against each other. By making as few changes to the rest of the program while doing analysis, I'm trying to ensure I don't inadvertently cause problems with my own work.

Comment: I see your point. It will be really helpful for others to answer if you can put these details in the question. Meanwhile, do you have the option of calling Bot class from main() method with different inputs? If yes then write a simple for loop in main() and call Bot multiple times with different input swithin the for loop. You can start and end time between each run.

Comment: No, the original main() is composed of a couple of loops, multiple method calls and even some output printing. It is definitely not well-coded, but I guess it's easier to interpret for beginners, for whom the course is aimed. @Aubin's answer will do for me, and in any case it seems like a very good way to achieve main() iteration with no modification of the original methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a second class named `<your-main-classname>PerfTest`, code a second static `main` method in it and from the inner loop call `<your-main-classname>.main( args )`.